# how to identify from which domain/url request is coming for my WCF REST service

Tags: wcf-security, wcf-rest

I have WCF REST Service...
Client accessing this service and I can see from Request headers what is the host and Origin of this request to my service.
But this can be tampered and I want to restrict my service to clients if the request to my service is coming from specified origin/domain/url?

Comment: You can also see the IP which can't be tampered with. It's better to add these restrictions at the IIS level though.

Comment: i want to get host name...so that i will check whether request for my service if from valid host or not?